# phpmyadmin success export but

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, xampp

```
Notice in .\libraries\tbl_columns_definition_form.inc.php#55
 Undefined variable: server

Backtrace

.\libraries\structure.lib.php#2452:     include(.\libraries\tbl_columns_definition_form.inc.php)
.\tbl_structure.php#45: PMA_displayHtmlForColumnChange(
string '201507',
string 'trxaktiv',
NULL,
string 'tbl_structure.php',
)
```

This happens when I browse the structure. What is wrong?

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version?

Comment: budling with xampp ( latest xampp )

Comment: So this would be XAMPP 5.6.11 which contains phpMyAdmin 4.4.12. Did you try the newer phpMyAdmin 4.4.13.1 ?

Comment: Version information: 4.4.13.1 (up to date)
thank you for your advise i will re-test 
so far no error